# iOS playing video faster than 2x speed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I want to play videos at a fast speed. I have searched around and found that AVPlayer and others can do playback speed to 2x. I am curious how I could go about playing a video at a rate faster than that?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `AVPlayer` is not able to play videos faster than 200% of the default speed. I did already lots of research on that, to be sure of that. Hope I could help you.

Please checkout the answer of the question, which I already asked. [Increase the maximum play rate of AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536308/increase-the-maximum-play-rate-of-avplayer)

Comment: So, is there any Solution for play Video Fast or Slow ?

Answer (score 1):

As kchromik [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27217867), 2.0 is the maximum rate at which `AVPlayer` will play a video smoothly. 
There is a workaround though:
You can create an `AVMutableComposition` and scale the time range to the desired one. After doing that, you can further multiply it using `AVPlayer`'s playback rate, up to 2x.

This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881237) explains how to do it.

[Swift version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866937/2829102).