# How to achieve a playback rate of 4.0 with AVPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

`player.rate = 4.0` doesn't work for me.

Is it a good way to achieve rate of 4.0 with `AVPlayer`, or there is a better approach?

Comment: wow, you're playing video fast. What do you trying to achieve? and what is your issue?

Comment: It seems like `AVPlayer` doesn't support a playback rate higher than 2.0, how can I get a playback with rate of 4.0.

Comment: I am not using MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Then try to use it. `AVPlayer` can't do so, you've to change.

Comment: just use [player setRate:4.0] and do not call [player play]; after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[AVComposition scaleTimeRange:toDuration:]` to produce a fast-motion `AVAsset`.

```
float rate = 4.0;
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:someURL];
AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
NSError *error = nil;
[composition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                     ofAsset:asset
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
[composition scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                 toDuration:CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, 1 / rate)];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Comment: Hey! Did you figure out how to update this composition on the fly? Should i remove the timeRange and than scale it again? and apply it to a new composition?